# How to configure jwt token in swagger header using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, swagger

I have configured swagger in  spring boot application but i dont know how to authenticate jwt authorization token the swagger version is 2.4.0

```
@Bean
public Docket newsApi() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .securitySchemes(Lists.newArrayList(apiKey()))
            .securityContexts(Lists.newArrayList(securityContext()));

}

@Bean
SecurityContext securityContext() {
    return SecurityContext.builder()
            .securityReferences(defaultAuth())
            .forPaths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();
}

List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
    AuthorizationScope authorizationScope
            = new AuthorizationScope("global", "accessEverything");
    AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[1];
    authorizationScopes[0] = authorizationScope;
    return Lists.newArrayList(
            new SecurityReference("JWT", authorizationScopes));
}

private ApiKey apiKey() {
    return new ApiKey("JWT", "Authorization", "header");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this issue today and found out that actually there is no way to do it **yet**.

Your code is already good enough for this task, there is just one thing missing: when you add the token in the UI, you need to also add "Bearer" before the token.

1. Click to add your authorization:
   [image: click to authorize]
2. Add "Bearer " + your token:
   [image: token with bearer]

I also tried to add the "Bearer" to the ApiKey, but it also don't work (because it generates double ":".

Hope it helps.